# Custom cache for module

Tags: module, cache

I've made a module that needs to cache its output by country, or not at all. I've found [this post](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9247/custom-component-no-cache-setting) which describes how to do it with a component, but how would you do it with modules?

To turn off cache completely, I've copied the relevant fields from XML config from mod_custom, set cache to off, and global cache to conservative. Still it caches.

Any tips welcome.

**Edit**: It seems a module is *always* cached when it's included within an article: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=527208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a comment on your last statement on embedded modules being always cached - our experience, in fact, [shows the complete opposite](http://www.itoctopus.com/the-hidden-downside-of-embedding-joomla-modules-in-articles). Our post is much more recent than the answer in the Joomla forum (the one on the Joomla forum is also for a very old version of Joomla - ours is for Joomla 3.x).

Now to answer your original question, you can always use the `get` and `store` methods of the [JCache class](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JCache.html). This way, you will be able to easily cache and retrieve your module's data.

Comment: Strange. Which version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: The post was about Joomla 3.x - not sure if this applies to the latest version though, but again, our post is much more recent than the post on the Joomla forum.